# Select Query and storing into a variable

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I am trying to select some data from a database and then store that value into a string for use later in the program. I believe I have to use a reader or something else?

This is my select query, which works fine.

```
string strSelect = "";
strSelect = "SELECT ID FROM Database.Table WHERE TEXT = '" + strWrongText + "' ";
DB2Command cmdSelectID = new DB2Command(strSelect, db2Connection);
cmdSelectID.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am using DB2 database/Connection.

I basically want to store ID from the database into a variable strID.

Any Ideas?

Comment: `var result = cmdSelectID.ExecuteQuery();`

Comment: DB2Command.Parameters should be used to specify the value of strWrongText to avoid injection vulnerabilities

Comment: Hi that seems to just return -1 every time. even though the ID in the database is 21. @dotctor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int ID = 0; 

string strSelect = "";
strSelect = "SELECT ID FROM Database.Table WHERE TEXT = '" + strWrongText + "' ";

DB2Command cmdSelectID = new DB2Command(strSelect, db2Connection);

ID = cmdSelectID.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: I cant seem to use ExecuteScalar. Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Ive managed to solve this by 
   ID = (int)cmdSelectID.ExecuteScalar();
and your answer works fine
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
       int id;
       string strSelect = "";
       strSelect = "SELECT ID FROM Database.Table WHERE TEXT = @TEXT;";       
       using(DB2Command cmdSelectID = new DB2Command(strSelect, db2Connection))
   {
       cmdSelectID.Parameters.Add("@TEXT", "strWrongText"); 
       using(DB2DataReader dr = cmdSelectID.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(dr.Read())
      {
         id = (int)dr["ID"];
      }
    }
   }
```

Always use parameters to avoid SQL Injection.
Notice the using keyword, the objects are disposed correctly. You read the value from database, convert it to your datatype and assign it to id variable int.

Comment: Hi, This just returns 0